# Change color of all clicked buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, onclick

I have a set of buttons in an html page of the following form:

```
<button
      id="testID"
      mat-mini-fab
      ngClass="list-button"
      (click)="onClick($event)"
    >
      Press
    </button>
```

I try to change the color of each button belonging to .list-button class after clicking on it using the following css code:

```
.list-button:focus {
  background-color: #7d698d;
}
```

However, while the color of the button I click each time changes
(the color of all the previously clicked buttons also changes back to their original color).
How could I fix it? I want all the clicked buttons to remain their new color.

I also tried assigning an id to the buttons of this class and changing their color inside the onClick() method as follows without success. The same problem remains. Could you help me, please?

```
  onclick(event: any) {
    const btn = document.getElementById('testID');
    if (btn) btn.style.backgroundColor = '#7d698d';
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- ID must be unique
- You can use the function and pass `el` which will refer to `this` as an argument  `function onClick(el){......}` and use it `onClick(this)`
- No need to get the `id` you can directly use `el.style`  or `event.target.style` see the next examples

```js
function onClick(el){
  el.style.backgroundColor = '#7d698d';
}
```

```html
<button
  id="testID-1"
  mat-mini-fab
  ngClass="list-button"
  onclick="onClick(this)"
>
  Press
</button>

<button
  id="testID-2"
  mat-mini-fab
  ngClass="list-button"
  onclick="onClick(this)"
>
  Press
</button>
```

**Also** You can use the function and pass `event` which equal `event` as an argument  `function onClick(event){......}` and use it `onClick(event)`

```js
function onClick(event){
  event.target.style.backgroundColor = '#7d698d';
}
```

```html
<button
  id="testID-1"
  mat-mini-fab
  ngClass="list-button"
  onclick="onClick(event)"
>
  Press
</button>

<button
  id="testID-2"
  mat-mini-fab
  ngClass="list-button"
  onclick="onClick(event)"
>
  Press
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for js. Use the `focus` selector in your stylesheet.

> The `:focus` selector is allowed on elements that accept keyboard events or other user inputs.

~ [W3](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp)

```css
button.list-button:focus {
  background-color: #7d698d;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button class="list-button">Click</button>
```

Edit ~ with js. This method uses `.querySelectorAll("button")` and toggles the styled class `.focus` each time the button(s) are clicked. This works well when having multiple buttons.

```js
// Get all the elements on the basis of query selector (button)
let btn = document.querySelectorAll("button");

for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  (function(index) {
    btn[index].addEventListener("click", function() {
      console.log("Clicked Button: " + index);

      let isPresent = false;

      // Checks if the class is present or not
      this.classList.forEach(function(e, i) {
        if (e == "focus") {
          isPresent = true;
        } else {
          isPresent = false;
        }
      });

      // Toggles the presence of class (.focus) on the basis of the isPresent variable
      if (isPresent) {
        this.classList.remove("focus");
      } else {
        this.classList.add("focus");
      }
    });
  })(i);
}
```

```css
.focus {
  background-color: #7d698d;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click</button>
<button id="btn">Click</button>
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

Comment: Unfortunately,  while clicking on another button that is on the page and that button belongs to the same class (list-button) the color of the previously clicked buttons still reverses back to their original :-\

Comment: @GeorgePerid added a `.js` solution which allows for buttons to stay focus when clicking on another.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the id of the button that fired the event

```
onclick(event: any) {
  const btn = document.getElementById(event.target.id);
  if (btn) btn.style.backgroundColor = '#7d698d';
}
```

Comment: You style an element not an id.

Comment: I just find a solution using class binding https://angular.io/guide/attribute-binding. I add/remove class (and consequently the button color) on click. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the color of the previously clicked buttons is resetting after you click on another one is that the focus is set on the last clicked button. Try using the code in the Venkatesh's answer.

Comment: hmm.. I have the same issue..